# RNA interference

Tags: genetics

If dsRNA is produced through a mutation (such as forming of a hairpin structure) in a particular gene and RNAi has become possible because of that, will an organism which is a heterozygote to this gene (whereby one of his alleles has the mutation and one doesn't) have his healthy allele be partially unaffected by the dominantly mutated allele when the siRNA doesn't fully bind to the healthy allele?

Comment: Josh - try editing your question... you have written one extremely long run-on-sentence that is difficult to follow (if you break it down and edit it will make it better)